# UPDATE not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have two statements here, and insert and an update. The insert works fine. However the UPDATE statement seems to do nothing.(i.e. the HomeCode column remains to be null) and when i try to print the stmt object, it says 0 rows are affected.

```
function insert_each_cell($row_count,$GradUnit, $LastName, $FirstName,$Initials,$SciTitle,
                $AppointStart,$AppointEnd,$SupLevel,$Restrictions,$Primary,$PrimGrad,
                $Grad1,$Grad2,$Grad3,$HomeAbbrev,$HomeCode,$HomeName,$UnivStartDate
                ,$UnivEndDate){
    global $conn;

    //insert strings
    $prep = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sgs_student_info (GradUnit, LastName, FirstName, Initials, SciTitle, Restrictions,PrimGrad, Grad1, Grad2,Grad3, HomeAbbrev, HomeName)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $prep-> bind_param("ssssssssssss",$GradUnit, $LastName, $FirstName,$Initials, $SciTitle, $Restrictions,$PrimGrad, $Grad1, $Grad2,$Grad3, $HomeAbbrev, $HomeName);
    $prep-> execute();
    $prep -> close();
    $prep = $conn->prepare("UPDATE sgs_student_info SET HomeCode=? WHERE id=?");
    echo $HomeCode. "<br>" . $row_count . "<br>";
    $prep->bind_param("ii", $HomeCode, $row_count);
    print_r($prep);
    echo "<br>";
    $prep->execute();
```

}

Comment: Where is `$row_count`?

Comment: it's a parameter that gets incremented every time i call the function insert_each_cell

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem

It was due to my $row_count being 1 more than the row that i'm currently on. 
so that row haven't been created yet, that's why update doesn't do anything